# Diasbling the Alt key and safely remove hardware icon in windows 7 via registry

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, alt

I was wondering if some one could help me to disable:

- The Alt key on the keyboard and
- The Safely remove hardware icon from the system tray in windows 7.

It would be good if I could do a registry hack to achieve this as I have a script that I would be adding to the windows startup directory and would like these changes to take effect when a user logs in.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It might be useful if you can provide more context as to why you're trying to do this.

Comment: @JamesSnell I am trying to develop a script which would run every time a user logs in and this particular script would restrict certain users.

Comment: ok - that's a good description of when you want to do it?  What do you want to actually achieve by doing it.  Disabling the alt-key is quite a specific thing to do and disabling a system key isn't something I'd show someone how to do without a very good reason when there may be a better way to reach to your eventual goal...

Comment: @JamesSnell We have an application where pressing the combination Alt+0160 pops up a window and with this window user can change the application's configuration. Unfortunately this cannot be disabled in the application itself so therefore I was searching for an alternative solution. We do not want the users to be able to access this window. These users are to be restricted as the PC where the application will be installed is a qualified environment and we do not want the users to fiddle around with the system.

Comment: ah ok.  Remapping / breaking the alt key entirely is probably excessive but something here might help... http://www.ghacks.net/2010/06/06/the-ultimate-guide-to-keyboard-remapping/

Answer (score 0):

From what I know you cannot disable a key using the registry although I could be wrong..

However the safely removed hardware icon is controlled by a registry key:

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\Systray

DWORD Services (should be set to 31) if you change this to 29 and test to see if it's the behavior you would like.. The problem is that it gets reset after Windows reboots so you will need to set upon login using a script as you mentioned...

Hope this helps...

Comment: @chaarlesH thanks for the reply, I will definitely give it a try.